# C++ polymorphism with references

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism

I've been writing some classes in C++ that operate on files. When I started, I made all my constructors accept one `std::string` argument that was interpreted as a filename, because that was quick and easy.

The only functions specific `std::fstream` that any of the classes use is `.open()`. I figured that since `std::ofstream` and `std::ostringstream` both derive from `std::ostream` and I was only using `std::ostream`'s functions, that it would be much better to have each constructor take an `std::ostream` or `std::istream` argument as appropriate, instead of keeping the classes bound to files.

A great textbook example of why polymorphism is useful. GCC is pretty unhappy about it though. This is a simplification of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Foo {
        public:
                Foo(std::istream&);
                std::istream& input;
};

Foo::Foo(std::istream& is) {
        this->input = is;
}

int main() {
        std::ifstream is("test.txt");
        Foo foo(is);
}
```

Which, when compiled with `g++ test.cpp`, produces the following colorful assortment of errors:

```
test.cpp: In constructor ‘Foo::Foo(std::istream&)’:
test.cpp:10:1: error: uninitialized reference member ‘Foo::input’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h: In member function ‘std::basic_ios<char>& std::basic_ios<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:791:5: error: ‘std::ios_base& std::ios_base::operator=(const std::ios_base&)’ is private
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:45:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_ios.h:64:11: error: within this context
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:41:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/istream: In member function ‘std::basic_istream<char>& std::basic_istream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/istream:56:11: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_ios<char>& std::basic_ios<char>::operator=(const std::basic_ios<char>&)’ first required here 
test.cpp: In constructor ‘Foo::Foo(std::istream&)’:
test.cpp:11:16: note: synthesized method ‘std::basic_istream<char>& std::basic_istream<char>::operator=(const std::basic_istream<char>&)’ first required here
```

I have trouble sifting through all the template arguments but it looks like it doesn't like `this->input = is;`. It's important for each class to be able to access the stream as a member, because various different member functions all have to be able to see it. I figured GCC would probably be nicer about a pointer, but to me, pointers to classes look suspiciously like dynamically allocated memory, and I only want to raise those suspicions if they're true. What's the right way to go about this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Members of a reference type (as well as members of a `const` type) must be initialized in the [constructor initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
Foo::Foo(std::istream& is) : input(is)
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^
{
}
```

The reason is that you need to **initialize** a reference immediately, before you do anything else with it. What you have in your original code is illegal for the same reason why this is illegal:

```
int y = 42;
int& x; // ERROR!
x = y;
```

Initialization lists, on the other hand, guarantee that your reference member is bound to an object *before* the body of the constructor is entered.

Comment: Good link and good explanation, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Change your code to the following:

```
Foo::Foo(std::istream& is) : input(is) {
}
```

What you have is an **assignment**, not **initialization**. You need to initialize the member in a member initialization list.

By the time you hit the body of the constructor `{`, all class members already exist in memory. So in the line `this->input = is;`, you are trying to assign `is` to an already existing object, however, references must be initialized in C++, hence the error message: `uninitialized reference member`.

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize your reference member at member initialization list.

```
Foo::Foo(std::istream& is): input(is) {
}
```

C++ reference cannot be assigned, therefore, it must be initialized in the initialization list.

Answer (score 2):

change your constructor this this

```
Foo::Foo(std::istream& is):input(is) {

}
```

the error is

```
error: uninitialized reference member ‘Foo::input’ [-fpermissive]
```

so you have to initialize `input`